# Expression type '@lvalue CGRect' is ambiguous without more context

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to create something using swift playgrounds and am having some difficulty with the auto layout. Here is my code

```
import PlaygroundSupport
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var gameVC = GameView()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        gameVC.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(gameVC)
        gameVC.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
        gameVC.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        gameVC.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstraint: view.frame.width).isActive = true
        gameVC.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstraint: view.frame.height).isActive = true
    }
}
```

I get errors on the line

```
gameVC.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstraint: view.frame.width).isActive = true
```

saying

> Expression type '@lvalue CGRect' is ambiguous without more context

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`view.frame.width` is not a constraint. You probably want

```
gameVC.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor).isActive = true
gameVC.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor).isActive = true
```

or maybe:

```
gameVC.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: view.frame.width).isActive = true
gameVC.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: view.frame.height).isActive = true
```

I actually think there is no such method called `constraint(equalToConstraint:)`.

Comment: Maybe worth filing a bug report about the unhelpful error message from Swift compiler?